# How to use imageMSO icons in add-in commands

Tags: office-js

We were able to implement customized images for the Excel add-in Ribbon commands based on configuration in Manifest file. Also we wanted to know that whether could it be able to implement with imageMSO icons on the same or any work around need to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a copy of the icons and host them with your other icons and then reference the copies in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks Rick for update and we were able to make copy of required icons by accessing in internet explorer and were able to resize as per standards in manifest.